# Does Redux care how my API is structured?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, rest, redux

As I'm diving into Redux this is the question that is stuck with me the most. There are tons of articles and tutorials about Redux but it seems there are lots of different opinions on how to deal with APIs.

In my case, I'm working on a full stack web app that will use two APIs to collect the necessary data we need for our React front-end.

REST API #1 will be developed outside of my web application, most likely written with Python/Flask.

REST API #2 is a Node/Express app that will communicate with API #1. And it will serve endpoints directly to our React/Redux front-end.

Now in our past applications, we structure our back-end with your typical data model and a controller to communicate with the front-end through an endpoint.

[image]

I think my confusion is coming in here. Is there a correct/incorrect way to build a REST API that needs to communicate with React/Redux? I like this diagram, but it obviously doesn't say anything specific about the API structure. Does Redux not care about the back-end structure? Can I build an endpoint as I described above and have Redux just call the appropriate endpoint?

Comment: It is my understanding that Redux does not care about the structure of the API endpoint. You can use whatever middleware you see fit (Redux Saga, redux promises, redux thunk).

Comment: Redux is all about effective state management. You just need to give it proper state. It can be an api developed with .net/php/node. Its just we need to connect it properly and if needed use redux-thunk kind of middlewares to achieve some extra functionality

Comment: @G_S That's good to hear. The words model/controller are what were throwing me off. As I read about Redux it's always advertised as a replacement to MVC. But it would still make sense to have a data model and controller when building the REST API?

Comment: @joshweir see comment above.

Comment: @23k I would suggest looking at this redux boilerplate on github: https://github.com/reactGo/reactGo it presents redux in the context of a mongodb backend - the mvc structure is boilerplated on the server side there: https://github.com/reactGo/reactGo/tree/master/server/db/mongo

Comment: @23k, with the help of comments and answers, i hope now its clear

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is my understanding that Redux does not care about the structure of the API endpoint. You can use whatever middleware you see fit (Redux Saga, redux promises, redux thunk).

[This redux boilerplate](https://github.com/reactGo/reactGo) should help understand one way of handing redux side effects using [redux-thunk](https://github.com/reactGo/reactGo/blob/master/app/actions/topics.js). The boilerplate also presents an example server side api using [expressjs and mongodb utilizing the MVC paradigm](https://github.com/reactGo/reactGo/tree/master/server/db/mongo).

[This is the redux-saga example](https://github.com/redux-saga/redux-saga/tree/master/examples/real-world).